# Como pegar atributos de um campo option com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<select name='exemplo' id='exemplo'>
    <option value='1' class='teste' dado='a'>1</option>
    <option value='2' class='teste' dado='b'>4</option>
    <option value='3' class='teste' dado='c'>3</option>
    <option value='4' class='teste' dado='d'>2</option>
</select>
```

Sei que para pegar o `value` do `option` selecionado posso usar:

```
$('#exemplo').change(function(){
    var valor=$(this).val();
)};
```

Mas e para pegar o atributo `dado`? Como faz?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Podes usar assim: `var dado = $(this).find(':selected').attr('dado');`

O [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) procura elementos descendentes, e o [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) garante que só escolhe os *selecionados*. Depois usando o [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) podes ir buscar esse atributo `dado`.

```
$('#exemplo').change(function() {
    var valor = this.value;
    var dado = $(this).find(':selected').attr('dado');
    console.log(valor, dado);
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/roc0a6pe/

Seria mais correto usares campos `data-`, pois convencionou-se que isso seria melhor. Nesse caso no HTML terias `data-dado='a'` e o código todo ficaria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/roc0a6pe/1/

### Podias também fazer isso sem jQuery...

Nesse caso o JavaScript seria assim:

```
var select = document.getElementById('exemplo');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var valor = this.value;
    var dado = this.querySelector('option:checked').dataset.dado;
    console.log(valor, dado);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/roc0a6pe/3/

Comment: Recomendo de usar `.bind(` é melhor e não `.change(`, por motivo depende a versão jQuery. `$('#exemplo').bind('change', function() {`

Comment: @KingRider o `.change()` foi adicionado na versão `1.0`. A mesma que o `.bind()`

Comment: Perfeito!! Obrigada

Comment: @Sergio, negativo e nada mesma, veja sobre dele, caso o navegador nem todas funciona função jquery e segue (http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/) ... esse vc colocou o codigo javascript puro muito bom, `option:checked` hum nem conhecia... bom saber, obrigado!

Comment: @KingRider é muito util, e já está bem suportado: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: @KingRider Sei que o `live`, `on`, `bind` e `delegate` são diferentes, mas aqui é o caso do `change` que foi adicionado juntamente com o `bind` na versão `1.0`: https://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.0/

Comment: Ual, essa dica me ajudou demais, obrigado @Sergio